# Logging into a website not using the websites front page?

Tags: java, android, html

Sorry for the vagueness of my questions here, but I wanted to know if it was possible to login into this website https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/entry.do through an a native phone app?

I've seen many apps which access data for the Oyster Card but there is no API for them to access this data and can only think they've logged into the website using the users details then extracting the necessary text to display within their app.

Here is a sample app alongside what the actual website looks like once logged in;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is, here is an example using WebView:

```
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/entry.do");


        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('j_username')[0].value = '"+ausername+"'");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('j_password')[0].value = '"+apassword+"'");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms[0].submit()");
            }
        });
```

This will show the common desktop version of the website but if you want a dedicated app for the site, it would be preferable with some sort of API for the site. Without an API, you are left with either the common desktop website, or DOM manipulation of the received html using regular HTTP requests.