# Load HTML page in background with javascript injection

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, widget

I create widget to display text from html-page.
I need way to load first html-page in memory (without `WebView`). Then I need send JavaScript injection to this page (complete form). Then I must receive **second** page and parse it to find necessary `div`. And put value of this div to widget.

I want it to be in background because I have only Widget and Service.

It is possible without  `WebView.loadUrl( myJavaScriptText);` after create WebView in Activity?

Any ideas please!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as for the login/form submit I have answered this before here: [Logging into a website not using the websites front page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070309/logging-into-a-website-not-using-the-websites-front-page/19071270#19071270)

To do this in the background, I would think that you possibly could wrap the code inside a hidden/invisible fragment.

Comment: Thank you, I already use similar javascript code for submit form. But main trouble is I dont have any visivility fragment when i can use WebView. I only have Widget and Service. In Widget impossible insert WebView. If I use Activity for insert WebView I lose background-style of this operations. When Activity create it will be open to user. I try use 'moveTaskToBack( true);' in 'onCreate' method, but Activity 50% open to user on few seconds. This is not best way...

Comment: Then perhaps you can use a HTTPClient request instead. Do not know about the form submission then, though. If you control the serverside it should be rather simple to create a direct url that can fetch the information using a GET request.

Comment: I can't control server side, and can't generate GET request. I must fill the form and send POST request by submit() or click() methods on form (with generate coockies and etc. session id by native javascript from alient serverside).